# Authentication Finally Failed on AWS ElasticSearch Service

Tags: laravel, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to install the AWS ElasticSearch Service on aws console. Wherein I have been able to set up the same properly. But when running it through the end-point URL, it states that, "Authenication finally failed."

URL:

```
https://search-indtuning-v2-elastic-ktcb6cvtse6jov5jcrsi4r27rq.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com/
```

Link:

```
Authentication finally failed
```

I am unable to get a complete reference on same. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate on your issue? I made some grammatical edits but you need to edit it with more technical details. The question seems unclear. I assume you're using AWS ElasticSearch Service and it's not inside a VPC. Have you tried a Curl command on the given URL?

Comment: Please try googling for `"Authentication finally failed" aws`.  This produces many places that existing answers for this problem might exist, including a number of SO questions.